# Android - get INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS boolean

Tags: android

I am trying to get around the INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS option which has two different versions. A pre-17 API level and 17+. I get a null pointer exception when I run this:

```
boolean unknownSource = false;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17) {
    unknownSource = Settings.Secure.getInt(null, Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS, 0) == 1;
} else {
    unknownSource = Settings.Global.getInt(null, Settings.Global.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS, 0) == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is API level 3 that the `Settings.System` variable was depreciated and changed over to `Settings.Secure` and then in API level 17 it changed over to `Settings.Global`.

Also, I believe the method call requires a Context Content Resolver.

```
boolean unknownSource = false;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 3) {
    unknownSource = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS, 0) == 1;
}
else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17) {
    unknownSource = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS, 0) == 1;
} else {
    unknownSource = Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS, 0) == 1;
}
```

Comment: This says it was introduced in API 3 : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS

Comment: Yea, I think it changed twice.