# Control Which Apps Can be Downloaded by User of MDM / MAM Controlled Device

Tags: android, security, wso2, mdm

I am working with WSO2's EMM (Enterprise Mobility Management) which is an open source MDM (Mobile Device Management) and MAM (Mobile App Management) solution. Specifically to implement a BYOD (Bring Your Own Device) program. I am unhappy with a few features.

**One main feature I want to implement myself is strict control over which apps can be installed by the user.**

> 1) By not allowing installation of apps from 'Unknown Sources'. That is to not allow the user to check the '**Allow Installation of Apps From Unknown Sources**' option or at least to be able to flag it if they do.
>
> 2) **Black-Listing** only specific apps that can be downloaded from the Play Store.
>
> 3) Even better would be the ability to **White-List** apps that can be downloaded form the Play Store
>
> 4) And in a perfect world I would like the ability to mix both an **Enterprise App Store and the above restrictions to Play Store** app downloads. (The benefit to that would be the ability to push corporate software to users, and still allow a safe and user friendly experience through the Play Store.)

Android's **Device Administration API** does not explicitly allow for these controls. Yet paid enterprise MDM solutions such as *AirWatch* boast these features. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time support of such features are patchy. As example Samsung SAFE provides more API (which will allow to do what you want) and Motorolla had some additional enterprise API.

So, you can't implemented it on generic Android, but rather you can implement it on some devices.

Second approach is compliance. May be you can't prevent installation or remove apps, but you can detect them and do some actions associated with it (revoke credentials, turn off enterprise email and so on).

Usually, MDM solutions have some mix of these two things.

Comment: Thanks! I could live with compliance, this MDM already detects any third party apps that are installed so I can work with that. But how can you tell if they the 'Unknown Sources' setting has been checked. I was rummaging through the settings.system class and found public **static final String INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS** . But it appears this isn't to 'get' that value. Do you know if there is a method to determine if that setting is enabled?

Comment: Take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776976/android-get-install-non-market-apps-boolean

Answer (score 1):

After much research I have found a few things I would like to share:

The current Android Device Administration API is very limited the features included are:

- Device password restrictions
- Disable camera
- Lock and wipe device
- Device Encryption

Beyond that (as Victor Ronin described in the above answer) your app can only check for compliance but can not enforce it.

> The only way to enforce policies beyond the scope of the Device
>   Administration API is to have *system level* permissions. The only way
>   to get these system level permissions is to have your app signed by
>   the OEM of the device running your software. This is exactly how
>   enterprise MDM solutions can enforce such rules, their apps are
>   actually signed by the OEM and then returned and distributed. Once
>   your UID is given the system permissions you can enforce most policies
>   needed to secure a device in the MDM scenario.

If interested watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ExX9_BN9XL8) it describes this scenario and a detailed system level exploit.